# data analysis question - calculate age in years according to mixed column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, series

so I have scoured the internet trying to figure out how to do this but I have not been successful.  I have a dataset of roughly 5,000 rows but for simplicity made this dataframe below.  I want to calculate the age IN YEARS (i.e. numbers with months are divided by 12) but I can't figure out how to let python identify the number.  Any ideas or direction you can point me in?

```
test = (3, 6, 1, '7 m', '8 m', 5, 11, '10 m','almost 4 m', '9 y & m', '3 Yr 7 mths')
test_list = list(test) 
test_series = pd.Series(test_list) 
df_test = pd.DataFrame(test_series) 
df_test.rename(columns = {0:'Key'}, inplace = True)
df_test['Years_Old'] = np.nan df_test
```

Comment: do you know if the number of years is always stored before the number of months?

Comment: what do you mean by 3,6? is this year of month?

Comment: So sometimes the entry is without a descriptor (like m or y) which implies that it is 'years'.  So 3 and 6 are 3 years old and 6 years old.

Answer (score 0):

With regular expressions we can first extract substrings like "[number][space(s) (optional)][y or m (optional)]" (case insensitive), then multiply [number]s by 1/12 if [y or m] is "m" (since we're counting number of years) and then sum it all up for each record:

```
import re

z = df_test['Key'].astype(str).str.extractall('(\d+)\s*([mMyYwW])?').fillna('m').astype({0: int, 1: str})
df_test['Years_Old'] = (z[0] * z[1].str.lower().map({'y': 1, 'm': 1/12, 'w': 1/52})).groupby(level=0).sum()

print(df_test)
```

Output:

```
            Key  Years_Old
0             3   0.250000
1             6   0.500000
2             1   0.083333
3           7 m   0.583333
4           8 m   0.666667
5             5   0.416667
6            11   0.916667
7          10 m   0.833333
8    almost 4 m   0.333333
9       9 y & m   9.000000
10  3 Yr 7 mths   3.583333
11         10 w   0.192308
```

Notes:

1. By default if no y/m is given I'm assuming months, but it's easy to switch to years if needed with `.fillna('y')` instead of `.fillna('m')` on the `z = ...` line
2. Not sure what "9 y & m" means, so treating it as just 9 years

Comment: Awesome, thank you 'perl' for this.  I'll be applying it shortly.

Comment: So I do this and the only issue was the 10th row.  It was adding 3 and 7 to get 10 then 10 divided by 12 which wasn't what I wanted.  I fixed it by making sure Y was lower case.  Which i did that previously in my actual df.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Oh, right, I was making some changes to make the code a bit less verbose and I forgot to include conversion to lowercase. I've updated the answer now, basically we can change it to `df_test['Years_Old'] = z[0].where(z[1].str.lower()=='y'...` with `.str.lower()`, which converts the column to lowercase, and then compares to 'y'. In this case it will work with both 'y' and 'Y' in the original dataset

Comment: The logic is the same. I've updated the code and added an example with "10 w" (last row) to my answer

Comment: After adding it to my actual df, I noticed there was also 'wk' for weeks. Where would this go back in to modify the calculations?

Comment: I've added an example with "10 w" (about 20 min ago), please have a look

Comment: Thank you for this, it worked like a charm!  I was reluctant to mention that it also had timestamps in it that I needed to handle.  I did so one at a time using replace.  I'm sure there's an easier way but I needed to move on to another step.  Thanks again!